# Application stopped working from task scheduler

Tags: c#, asp.net, command-line

I have created a window console application. Which will take one command line parameter (true/false) from window task scheduler.

I am not completely aware of this process.

I am using this code to read the argument :

```
bool dateOffset = false;
if (args.Length > 0)
{
    bool.TryParse(args[1], out dateOffset);
}
```

But when I am running the program from task scheduler....it showing error like..Application Name has stopped working exception..

I am not sure whether problem is in my code or task scheduler..My code works fine when I debug it without arguments..

Comment: You should probably take the first argument which would be args[0].

Comment: that was it..thanks alot..how can I miss that ..thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably take the first argument which would be args[0].

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in the following:

```
bool.TryParse(args[1], out dateOffset);
```

Arrays in C# are (usually) 0-based, which means the first item in the array is item 0, not item 1.

Try changing your code to:

```
bool.TryParse(args[0], out dateOffset);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have 1 argument, `args[1]` should be: `args[0]`

Answer (score 1):

Here: `if (args.Length > 0)` you are checking to see if the args array has at least one element.

However, `bool.TryParse(args[1], out dateOffset);` is trying to access the second element in an array.

Guess what happens when your if condition passes with a length of 1 but you try to access the second element.

Try using `args[0]`